# Why it's not safe to cast `char **` to `const char **`?

Tags: c, pointers

Compile this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    char *s = "helo";
    char **sp = &s;
    const char **csp = sp;
    const char *cs = *csp;
    printf("%s\n", cs);
}
```

get the warning:

```
cc.c: In function ‘main’:
cc.c:6:24: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     const char **csp = sp;
```

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/constptrptr-conversion.html <-- I know there is a duplicate SO answer somewhere, but this is the answer.

Comment: Not really a duplicate, that question is about C++ and the example is fine in C++ but produces a warning in C. https://godbolt.org/z/cdMvW54s5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char **sp`

> sp is a pointer to pointer to char and sp, *sp, and **sp are all
>   mutable

`const char **csp`

> csp is a pointer to pointer to const char and, csp and *csp are
>   mutable but **csp is const

Now lets see why `const char** csp = sp` is not safe.

```
const char Imconst = 'A';
char* ImMutable;
const char** ImConstPtr = &ImMutable;  // This is illegal but if it is allowed
*ImConstPtr  = &Imconst;
*ImMutable = '1'; // We are trying to assign to "Imconst"
```

Hope this clears the doubt.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is because char ** and const char ** are not equivalent. To be correct, you could fix the prototype (callee), or fix the caller (const char *).

find fantastic article at http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html